# Programmatically create contact list

Tags: list-manager

I know how to programmatically add contacts to a contact list, either through the contact itself, or through the List Manager API:

```
xContact.SetListSubscriptionsFacet(xConnectClient, listId);
```

Source: https://www.brimit.com/blog/sitecore-9-list-manager-changes

```
var subscriptionService = serviceLocator.ServiceProvider.GetService<ISubscriptionService>();
subscriptionService.Subscribe(contactListId, contactId);
```

Source: https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/digital_marketing/the_list_manager/the_list_manager_api

But none of these services have anything on how to programmatically *create* a list. I can probably do it a dirty way by manually adding an item to `/sitecore/system/Marketing Control Panel/Contact Lists` (based on `Contact List` template), but if Sitecore needs to do some indexing or other things when creating lists, this will of course not be enough.

So how can I programmatically create a contact list?

Sitecore 9.0.2 (rev. 180604)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the code which allows to create a contact list programatically in Sitecore:

```
private Guid CreateContactList()
{
    ContactListModel entity = new ContactListModel();
    Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();
    entity.Id = guid.ToString();
    entity.Type = ListType.ContactList.ToString();
    entity.Name = "My new contact list";

    IRepository<ContactListModel> contactListRepository = (IRepository<ContactListModel>) ServiceLocator.ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(IRepository<ContactListModel>));
    contactListRepository.Add(entity);
    return guid;
}
```

Remember to add references to:

- Sitecore.ListManagement.Services.dll
- Sitecore.Marketing.dll
- Sitecore.Services.Core.dll

Comment: Even though JacobNielsen's code was shorter, yours actually worked! My comment under his answer has many questions, and your code solved all of them.

Comment: Can I edit the destinationpath of the contactlist? I.e. I want it one step further down inside a folder. ../../ContactLists/FolderA/mynewcontactlist

Answer (score 6):

For Sitecore 9.x, you need to go through the `IDefinitionManager<IContactListDefinition>` from Sitecore.Marketing.dll. As an example:

```
string name = ItemUtil.ProposeValidItemName("name");
var listId = Guid.NewGuid();
string alias = ItemUtil.ProposeValidItemName(FormattableString.Invariant($"{name}-{listId}"));; //alias must be unique for each language variant
CultureInfo cultureInfo = Context.Language.CultureInfo;
string createdBy = Sitecore.Context.User.Name;

var definitionManager = ServiceLocator.ServiceProvider.GetService<IDefinitionManager<IContactListDefinition>>();
definitionManager.SaveAsync(new ContactListDefinition(listId, alias, cultureInfo, name, DateTime.UtcNow, createdBy), true);
```

A few notes:

The alias must be unique, which is why List Manager by default appends the item ID. It's not required to append the ID though, as long as the alias is unique.

In List Manager you will see lists created in the context language of the user, so you'll want to make sure you're setting creating the list using the corresponding CultureInfo.

Comment: just out of curiosity, is the method from my answer no longer valid in Sitecore 9?

Comment: @MarekMusielak No, you're right, yours is valid too. I'm happy to delete this answer if you think?

Comment: Do not delete your answer. It's only 2 lines while mine is much longer. I was just curious if mine is not correct. You're the expert! :)

Comment: @JacobNielsen Thanks! A few questions: I notice that lists created from List Manager have the item ID appended to the item Name, and the item created from your code does not do this. Is this important and I should append the ID myself, or does it not matter? I also noticed that the item created from your code was added as "English (US)" language item, and the ones created from List Manager are "English (region)". (I'm using `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` where you have `culture`) Why is that? And finally I created a new list, but I can't see it in ListManager. Anything else I need to do?

Comment: @GTHvidsten I've updated the answer to clarify

Comment: @JacobNielsen Your clarification solved the language and item name questions, but unfortunately the list does still not appear in List Manager

Comment: I missed the second parameter to SaveAsync.. activate = true. 
@MarekMusielak's answer is likely what you're looking for, as it's really just a wrapper around the definition manager, but I'm leaving this here as you have a few more options to play around with using this API

Comment: Can I edit the destinationpath of the contactlist? I.e. I want it one step further down inside a folder. ../../ContactLists/FolderA/mynewcontactlist  @JacobNielsen